# Burninate `error-*` tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate, burninate-request

Apparently there are a number of [tags named for specific ArcGIS error messages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-999999+or+error-000732+or+error-000539+or+error-000628+or+error-000840+or+error-000824+or+error-000358+or+error-000210+or+error-010328+or+error-000989+or+error-00090).

The full list is below:

[error-999999](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-999999)
[error-000732](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000732)
[error-000539](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000539)
[error-000628](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000628)
[error-000840](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000840)
[error-000824](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000824)
[error-000358](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000358)
[error-000210](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000210)
[error-010328](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-010328)
[error-000989](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-000989)
[error-00090](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-00090)

Is there some precedent for why these tags were created? If not, is there any objection to deleting them?

Comment: Related SO discussion: [Do we really need a tag for every error code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274616/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code)

Comment: The case against is not overwhelming (nett 3 upvotes saying to keep these tags) but I think sufficient to set [meta-tag:status-declined] on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've started to create these when I see the same errors being asked about repeatedly.

If a specific error message is only present in a small number < 10 I would not consider creating.  However, there are some that are getting up into the 50+ range, and with so many new users coming on board I see them as being likely to get into the "few hundred over the next few years" range.

By using a tag to group them it becomes possible to more quickly locate duplicates and look for causes behind them.  For example, a [self-assembling FAQ on `error-999999`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-999999?sort=frequent) provides more targeted insight than a [search for the error message in questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22error%20999999%22%20is%3Aquestion) alone (even when sorted by votes).

W.r.t. the related discussion https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274616/do-we-really-need-a-tag-for-every-error-code - my answer to that would be "No - but for some of them such tags are useful" and certainly much more useful than our erstwhile [error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) tag - now that I think should be a candidate for burnination.

Comment: "Error 999999" could mean almost anything, so I'm not sure that one is particularly useful, and ArcGIS error codes in general are notoriously vague/misleading. There is also the "problem" that these are all ArcGIS-specific errors, yet no mention of ArcGIS in the tag name or tag wikis. However if people think they are useful I'm not opposed to keeping them around. It is somewhat amusing that no other software on this site has an error code tag, though. I'm not sure whether this is more a reflection of usage/traffic patterns or software quality :) I agree that the `error` tag is utterly useless.

Comment: @blah238 If/when "ArcGIS error codes in general are notoriously vague/misleading" is the main reason that I started these error-* tags about 6 months ago as a bit of an experiment.  I think it is a way to get more from error messages like canonical ArcGIS/GIS answers here, improved ArcGIS/GIS documentation of errors, and ideally less ArcGIS/GIS errors.  There's work to do on the wikis later.  I'm not keen to prepend or append `arcgis` onto each tag name, unless a need for disambiguation from the same error number in a different GIS product emerges.